# Autoscroll for an internal scrollbar in a div element

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar, transform

I'm trying to do an autoscroll through javascript of an internal div which as the function of scrollbar.

Here the html snippet code:

```
<div class="scrollpane" style="display: block;">
<div class="scrollbar" style="transform: translate(0px, 0px); height: 25px;"></div>
</div>
```

With the following script I'm able to move the scrollbar on the bottom (0px, 200px) but still doesn't load the data.

```
var scrollbar=document.querySelectorAll('div.scrollbar'); scrollbar[0].setAttribute('style','transform: translate(0px, 200px); height: 25px;');
```

What am I missing here? Maybe some event that must be fired?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/fRUUd/1511/
Code $(".scrollbar").animate({ scrollTop: 1000 }, 2000);